# Using PHP Activerecord Finders in Classes

Tags: php, class, activerecord

I'm trying to test if a record exists with the following code using PHP Activerecord:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {

    public function user_exists() {
        $user = User::find_by_email($this->email);
        if ( $user ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

$user = new User();
$user->email = "test@email.com";

if ( $user->user_exists() ) {
    echo "user exists";
} else {
    echo "no user";
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting a 'Call to undefined method: find_by_email' error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `exists` method:

```
User::exists(array('email' => $this->email));
```

Which is faster because it only checks for existence but does not fetch the data.

Or even better; use model validations:

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations#validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: This is good. Does "exists" replace "find" within a class's method? Why doesn't "find" work at all?

Comment: No `find` within a class should work also, could `User` be a reference to a class with the same name? Maybe `static::find_by_email` does work?

Comment: Good point. BTW, for what I need right now, "exists" works great. Thanks.